# Snowflake Copy Into : Is there a Skip Header option but for the end of a file?

Tags: csv, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to copy a file into a table that has text at the start (think date, etc.) and then text at the end (also like date, "end of data", etc.). The rest of data are separated values that I can use the field delimiter for. I know I can skip headers in the COPY INTO but is there a way to end the COPY INTO at a certain point so that it doesn't try to ingest the end of data text?

Comment: What happens if you just load the file with that last row? Does it throw an error? Would you let Snowflake "ignore the lines with errors"?

Comment: How would I ignore the lines with errors? It throws an error due to a mismatch with varchar lengths but does load when I make the column varchar longer

Comment: ON_ERROR = CONTINUE or ON_ERROR = SKIP_FILE_2 might work for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Snowflake to copy the whole file into a table, and ignore errors:

```sql
copy into table1
from @stage1
on_error = continue
```

If the last row of the file is throwing errors, then this will happily import all of the correctly formed rows.

Comment: This has the unfortunate consequences of never failing even if there is another record in it that is also incorrect.  This is why I suggested `SKIP_FILE_2` which would then not load the file if there was "another" issue record in it.

Comment: Yes indeed, but also see the note that `SKIP_FILE action buffers an entire file whether errors are found or not. For this reason, SKIP_FILE is slower than either CONTINUE or ABORT_STATEMENT`. There's also the option `VALIDATION_MODE` to check for errors before loading.

Comment: Just need to weigh the need for the performance vs. the ability to fail a load appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe suggested, first test your file in VALIDATION_MODE=RETURN_ALL_ERRORS or RETUR_2_ROWS and see how it behaves .Based off that you can decide which option to use.